# HashMap (Java) giving wrong results

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a hash map in which each entry corresponds to 3 values
Key   object values ( which are two in number)

I have created a class ,whose object i create and store the results in a hash map
This is my code below in which i compare my incoming data with the previous values in the hash map.If the same data comes then i just increment the counter of that data. I have taken the print statements in the the for loop . though the two strings match but still my code never comes in the if loop for increment the counter.Why?

```
 for(i=1;i<=hMap.size();i++)
 {
      String skey = Integer.toString(i);
      if(hMap.get(skey).olddata==comingdata)
      {
           hMap.get(skey).counter=  hMap.get(skey).counter+1;
      }
 }
```

Comment: You don't compare objects with `==`.

Comment: in other words, use object.equals(otherObject)

Comment: comingdata is a string and hMap.get(skey).olddata is also a string but it is a string of an object

Comment: @Natasha - a `String` *is* an `Object`.

Comment: @Natasha: Right, if it's a string then the compare-by-identity problem is indeed the issue. As I've said before, you should definitely give more information when asking a question: see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Natasha: Why would it create problems? You don't have to post the full code - just enough to show the problem. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem needn't include any intellectual property of importance, etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have posted my code in new post with different problem.Kindly help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141820/hashmap-code-not-giving-the-desired-results/9141834#9141834

Comment: @Natasha: Your question shows that you haven't overridden `equals`, and your comment to the answer there suggests you should really read a Java book from the start. While Stack Overflow is a great site for answering specific questions, it's not a good site to learn the basics of a programming language (like overriding methods in Java).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given nearly enough information about the types involved, but, but I strongly suspect that this is the problem:

```
if(hMap.get(skey).olddata==comingdata)
```

That will be comparing *references*, rather than for equality, if `olddata` and `comingdata` are references of some kind. (EDIT: By the sounds of it, they're string references.)

My guess is that you want:

```
String skey = Integer.toString(i);
if(hMap.get(skey).olddata.equals(comingdata))
{
   hMap.get(skey).counter=  hMap.get(skey).counter+1;
}
```

Or rather more efficiently, avoiding pointless lookups:

```
WhateverType value = hMap.get(Integer.toString(i));
if (value.olddata.equals(comingdata))
{
    value.counter++;
}
```

I'd also suggest that if you're always going to look up by an integer, why not use an `Integer` key instead of always converting the integer into a string?

Additionally, it's worth following Java naming conventions, and you should make your fields private if they're not already.

If none of this helps, please post more code. The chances of the problem being in `HashMap` rather than in your code are incredibly small.

Answer (score 1):

You don't compare objects with `==` in Java unless you're trying to see if they have the same *reference value*.

```
if (hMap.get(skey).olddata.equals(comingdata)) {
...
```

You also shouldn't be exposing `olddata` like that; it should be available via a getter; e.g. `getOldData()`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear the type of `olddata`, but maybe you should compare the values using `equals()`:

```
if (hMap.get(skey).olddata.equals(comingdata))
```

In Java, `==` is used for either comparing primitive data types for *equality* or comparing object types for *identity*. If you need to compare two object types for *equality*, then you must use the `equals()` method, which is defined for all objects since it's inherited from the `Object` class, being aware that you also must override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your class, providing implementations meaningful for that class.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if(hMap.get(skey).olddata.equals(comingdata))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually mean `comingdata.equals(hMap.get(skey).olddata)`? Furthermore be aware that `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` must be correclty implemented.

Comment: Johannes - the keys are `String` instances, and I can guarantee that `String` implements `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` correctly.